# Number comparisons in BusyBox ash

Tags: shell-script, busybox, ash

I have the following script that extracts data from the *EXIF* command on my `busybox ash`-based system.  I parse the *date* tag from the end of the file and use `case` as a final check to ensure the format is correct.  My problem is the `if` statement at the end always seems to return true; *i.e.* `d="$e - Jebby (exif"` always runs.  If I `echo $en` and `echo $dn` it shows *$en* is greater than *$dn* but the `if` statement still runs the `d="$e - Jebby (exif"`.

```
x=<valid filename>
e=$(exif -d -m -t 0x9003 -- "$x" 2>/dev/null)
let l=${#e}-18
e=$(expr substr "$e" $l 19)
e="${e%[ ][0-2][0-9][:][0-6][0-9][:][0-6][0-9]*}" 
e="${e##*[!1-2][!09][!0-9][!0-9][!:][!0-1][!0-9][!:][!0-3][!0-9]}"
e=$(expr substr "$e" 1 4)$(expr substr "$e" 6 2)$(expr substr "$e" 9 2)
case "$e" in 
   [1-2][09][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9])
     let en=$e+3
     ds="${d% - Jebby (}"
     let dn=$ds
     if [ $en -lt $dn ]; then
        d="$e - Jebby (exif"
     fi
esac
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ you're using `ash`, not `bash` or some other shell? AFAIK `ash` has no `let` built in.

Comment: It is a Synology NAS running busybox which my understanding is close to ash shell.  Let is present but declare is not.

Comment: Ah, OK, my local version of `ash` gives various error messages when trying to run your code so I can't really test. You should probably quote the variables you are comparing: `if [ "$en" -lt "$dn" ];`

Comment: I don't know what `ds="${d% - Jebby (}" is supposed to expand to, but when you assign that value to dn, it doesn't look like a number, so the numeric `lt` comparison fails in unexpected ways. Echo out the values of $en and $dn for a failing case to confirm.

Comment: `let` works fine in `ash`. If you want to try yourself you can download a busybox binary here: https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/

Comment: @michas, How would a `busybox` binary explain what's missing in `ash`?  I've never seen any version of `ash` that includes a `let`, if you know of one, please include a URL to that version.

Comment: @agc busybox is a multicall binary which is its own `ash`. Just take the binary from the link above and run `./busybox ash`.

Comment: @michas, thanks, that explains it.  Have tweaked OP somewhat to reflect `busybox ash` invocation, but it may need more rewording to clarify this fact.

Answer (score 2):

For me comparison in ash works fine:

```
./busybox ash
$ [ 1 -lt 2 ] && echo true || echo false
false
$ [ 3 -lt 2 ] && echo true || echo false
true
$ a=1 b=2 c=3
$ [ $a -lt $b ] && echo true || echo false
true
$ [ $c -lt $b ] && echo true || echo false
false
$
```

What exactly is the content of your variables? You are aware that `-lt` compares numerically?

You might also do `set -x` to see what is going on.

Comment: On my BusyBox v1.22.1 the first one actually returns true and the second false ("1 less than 2" is supposed to be truthy, i.e. zero). On an unrelated note, sad to see this question closed because it is genuinely helpful.